# ErrorException in RoleController.php line 44: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am stuck about a problem, in fact I want to create a `Role` and a `Permission`. In my form.

I added the informations for each fields.

[image]

I have an error message:

`ErrorException in RoleController.php line 44:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

[image]

Comment: Share your form too.

Comment: @zahid hasan emon: Sorry, I have edited my first message... thanks

Comment: please can you show how you pass `$permissions` to your view?

Comment: seems ok to me. try dd($request->permission); and check what it shows.

Comment: Shouldn't you be iterating `$request->permissions` instead of `$request->permission` (note the s).

Comment: @Mohammed Aktaa: my problem is not my code. When I do a refresh it works..

Comment: @zahid hasan emon: when I do a refresh it works, is it a cookie problem? I have edited my first post.

Comment: @namelivia: Visibly, my problem is not in my code but in my cookies

Comment: what dd shows in the first occurence?